# Where does the term "my bag" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases

What is the origin of the term "my bag"? As in,

> That's just not **my bag**.

I know what it means. Essentially, for the example above, it would mean "That's not my sort of thing."

I know it's been around a while, since 60s hero [Austin Powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Powers_%28film_series%29) was always saying it. So I'm guessing it's 60s slang, that's still hanging on today.

But why a "bag"? Did "bag" get used to mean a generic thing in other context? Is it short for something, or rhyming slang. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if its the same, but I've heard and use - That's just not my bag of tea. I wonder if "my bag" is just short for "my bag of tea"... "my cup of tea" is another, similar phrase. "That's not my sort of thing." is exactly what "not my bag/cup of tea" means.

Comment: @Justin808 Interesting thought. I'd never have thought of that.

Comment: Definitely an interesting thought, but unlikely to be true. Interesting notion to have flutter by, though.

Comment: @Justin808 I believe that [tea-bag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=teabag) is a wee bit more colourful. [NSFW]

Comment: @coleopterist Erm...wish I hadn't just clicked on that link. Thanks, Urban dictionary for ever-broadening my horizons in directions I really didn't want.

Comment: @coleopterist That's *definitely* not my thing. Or bag. Or cup of tea. Or indeed, anything else.

Comment: An interesting, non-athoratative, [read](http://mysenseofenglish.blogspot.com/2011/04/not-my-cup-of-tea-vs-not-my-bag.html) "not my bag" may be a drug reference in relation to  preferred choice, this also fits with the 60s theme.

Comment: I assumed it had to do with Bagism, the concept that Lennon/Ono came up with to raise awareness of bigotry. I can see where they may have been inspired by existing London slang. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagism

Answer (score 9):

### *OED*

The OED defines this *bag* as:

> c. *fig.* A preoccupation, mode of behaviour or experience; a distinctive style or category; esp. a characteristic manner of playing jazz or similar music. Cf. *bag of tricks* at sense 18a. *slang* (orig. *U.S.*).
>
> 1960   J. Hendricks in D. Cerulli et al. *Jazz Word* (1962) 140   Lack of acceptance is a drag... Man, that's really in another bag.
> 1962   *Jazz Jrnl.* Mar. 30   ‘Bag’ is a current piece of trade jargon for hip musicians, and means something between a personal style and a body of work.

They further say:

> ***(not) to be one's bag** slang* (orig. *U.S.*): (not) to match one's personal style, taste, or preference; (not) to form part of one's interest, preoccupation, or area of expertise. Usually in negative contexts. Cf. thing *n.*1 4d.
>
> 1966   *N.Y. Times* 20 Nov. d13/2   They were trying to categorize me..as a racial satirist, but that's not my bag. Let's say I deal in universal human foibles.

---

### 1961 examples

I found some 1961 examples of this sense of *bag*.

[*Billboard*](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22in%20a%20latin%20bag%22&source=bl&ots=jp58IV7pFl&sig=Vd7Tu_dwgLLAEJBW1NPL75Ma3H0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iKhsULHBBKai4gS0kICoAg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg) magazine (6 Nov 1961) contains the following in a list of new LPs to be released by Verve. [Cal Tjader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cal_Tjader) was a Latin jazz musician and [Verve Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verve_Records) is an American jazz record label

> STAN GETZ AND BOB BROOKME YER— V-V6-8418 (Nov.)
> **IN A LATIN BAG— Cal Tjader— V-V6-8419 (Nov.)**
> THE TRIO— Oscar Peterson, Ray Brown, Ed Thigpen— V-V6-8420 (Nov.)
> BUDDY RICH BLUES-CARAVAN— V-V6- 8425 (Nov.)

[*Billboard*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=diAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%22in%20a%20latin%20bag%22&source=bl&ots=Kes4VX02Nm&sig=6zSxqiG9bRc_EbMXAoyVde1t6n0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iKhsULHBBKai4gS0kICoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20a%20latin%20bag%22&f=false) of 20th November 1961 has an advert from Verve:

> IN A LATIN BAG-Cal Tjader's torrid group in a program of crackling Latin-American jazz. Sensational sound!

And *[Billboard](http://books.google.fi/books?id=eiAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=%22in%20a%20latin%20bag%22&source=bl&ots=XKF512D8OW&sig=2SHvFQV7dhlF-Zk3xPJqRw8Kd6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iKhsULHBBKai4gS0kICoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20a%20latin%20bag%22&f=false)* of the following week (27 Nov 1961) has a review:

> IN A LATIN BAG Cal Tjader. Verve V 8419— Here's a warm and winning jazz set, which which combines Latin rhythms with jazz, and does it stylishly. Cal Tjader, with Armando Peroza, Paul Horn, Al McKibbon, Wilfredo Vicent, Johnny Re and Lonnie Hewitt, handle the charts with ease, and the disk marks a noteworthy debut for Tjader on the label. The tunes are mainly originals, sparked by by Tjader's "Davito" and "Paunetos Point," plus good readings of "Speak Low," and "Ben Hur," from the current flick. Lucid, meaningful jazz here.

A snippet of [*Down beat*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=1MsSAAAAIAAJ&q=%22jazz%20bag%22&dq=%22jazz%20bag%22&source=bl&ots=zsgyN8Ar7m&sig=LFYkN5eHGfAe46SyUROancoCR4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a6hsUL6iGKfb4QTejIDYBQ&redir_esc=y) magazine dated 1961 includes a review of Tina Brooks' *True Blue* album, released in 1960:

> *Soul* is appropriately earthy, medium tempoed, and melodically a bit doubtful as to **what jazz bag it belongs in**.

Comment: +1 Bingo. And by 6/2/65 it's in the pop world with James Brown's "Papa's Got a Brand New Bag".

Comment: I've been reading "The New Mrs. Clifton" by Elizabeth Buchan and one of the characters just used the expression "that's not my bag" ... in 1945. I know that expression wasn't around until the 1960s. It's disconcerting when someone makes such an obvious error and you're left wondering how an editor didn't catch it if the author was remiss. Buchan is such a good writer, I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 4):

[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bag) is usually the best place to check for that sort of thing.  That site reads:

> Meaning "person's area of interest or expertise" is 1964, from Black English slang, from jazz sense of "category," probably via notion of putting something in a bag.

When you first asked the question, I wondered if the origin might have had something to do with a tea bag, since, if something is my *bag*, it's generally also my *cup of tea*. Apparently not; according to [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/my-cup-of-tea.html):

> People or things with which one felt an affinity began to be called 'my cup of tea' in the 1930s. Nancy Mitford appears to be the first to record that term in print, in the comic novel Christmas Pudding, 1932:
>
> *I'm not at all sure I wouldn't rather marry Aunt Loudie. She's even more my cup of tea in many ways*.

Comment: +1. Exactly. I read the same thing [here](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/622976).

Comment: Based on the OPs given meaning "That's not my sort of thing." I think he is referring to `my bag of tea`.

Comment: @Justin808 If you believe that and can back it up (so it's not just a personal supposition) then make it an answer. It may well be that JR/Etymonline is correct and *bag of tea* derived from *bag* as "category" by analogy with "cup of tea", rather than the other way round.

Comment: @Justin: One website I found shows that _cup of tea_ goes back to at least the 1930s. If "that's my _bag_" is really from 1960s Black English slang (which seems [plausible](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+not+my+bag&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)), then the the word _bag_ being related to _tea bag_ would be almost surely coincidental.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Not posting an answer because I have nothing to back it up other than I use it as do my friends/family :)

Comment: I have just a vague idea that it might have its origin in the game bag and its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I can remember the '60's and I was there. . .in New York City, LA, SF, etc. it's not a reference to tea, but a musician's expression. I hung out with some of them. To the best of my memory, the saying was actually: "It's not IN my bag," short for: "it's not in my bag of tricks." Then, the word "in" was dropped by roughly 1975, and the expression became "it's not my bag."  It is my recollection that "bag of tricks" referred to what you did, liked, etc. So, "It's not my bag" means "I'm not into it."